# asp.net + jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a main page (default.aspx) with one textbox (TextBox1) and one linkbutton (LinkButton1).

When clicking LinkButton1 a jquery ui dialog box opens with content loaded from page popup.aspx (using the load method).

Popup.aspx contains 3 linkbuttons.

When clicking one of the linkbuttons I would like the linkbutton text to be passed back to default.aspx and inserted into TextBox1.

Any solutions???

**Source DEFAULT.ASPX:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenDialog() {
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>').load('./Popup.aspx').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: "Please select value", close: function (ev, ui) { $(this).dialog('close'); } });
        $dialog.dialog("open");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenDialog(); return false;">Open selector</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Source POPUP.ASPX:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Value 1</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">Value 2</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server">Value 3</asp:LinkButton>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to get the elements from the top window, and this is done by using the **window.top.document** as:

```
jQuery("#ElementID", window.top.document)
```

and then because you can not know from each page how the id is rendered to use static mode `ClientIDMode="Static"` for each control to keep it as you write it for example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" ClientIDMode="Static runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
```

So for example from the dialog you can send a text to the main window as:

```
jQuery("#TextBox1", window.top.document).text(jQuery("#LinkButton1").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=LinkButton]', function(){
    $('#TextBox1').text($(this).text());
});
```